# NullReferenceException в Navigation Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Есть две модели:

```
    public class Interval
{
    [Required]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public short Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("От")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime TimeFrom { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("До")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime TimeTo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Delivery> Deliveries { get; set; }
}

    public class Delivery
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Дата доставки")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Вес")]
    [Range(0, 5)]
    public byte Weight { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Количество мест")]
    [Range(0, short.MaxValue)]
    public short SeatAmount { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Цена")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Range(0, double.MaxValue)]
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Время доставки")]
    public int IntervalId { get; set; }

    public virtual Interval Interval { get; set; }

}
```

Почему при обращении к навигационному свойству Interval

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var interval = db.Deliveries.First().Interval;
        DateTime datetime = interval.TimeTo; //Здесь я получаю NullReferenceException
    }
```

Используется подход Code first. В контексте оба DbSet`a присутствуют. Естественно записи Deliveries есть, и у каждой из них IntervalId есть, не пустой.

UPDATE:
Задача была на внимательность ) Как видим тип первичного ключа в таблице Intervals - int, а внешний ключ в таблице Deliveries - short.

Comment: Получаете потому что db.Deliveries.First().Interval возвращает null. Что там у него внутри - неизвестно.

Comment: Хм. Вы уверены, что вам не нужна аннотация для поля `Interval`?

Comment: >> Естественно записи Deliveries есть, и у каждой из них IntervalId есть, не пустой.

Это противоречит тому, что вы получаете. Ищите ошибку в инициализации Interval.Deliveries.

Comment: Получаете потому что db.Deliveries.First().Interval возвращает null. Что там у него внутри - неизвестно.
_______________________________________
Это навигационное свойство. По этому свойству он должен вернуть объект Interval, так как у первой выбранной записи Deliveries IntervalId = 1. Вот он и должен вернуть объект Interval с Id = 1.
_______________________________________
Хм. Вы уверены, что вам не нужна аннотация для поля Interval?
_______________________________________
Аннотация для чего? Для IntervalId она есть, а для навигационного свойства она и не нужна.

Comment: Это противоречит тому, что вы получаете. Ищите ошибку в инициализации Interval.Deliveries.
______________________________________
Я прекрасно получаю db.Deliveries.First(). И даже могу читать любые свойства этого объекта. Но по навигационному свойству ничего не получаю.

Comment: Возможно вы отключили LazyLoad и навигационные свойства у Вас не подтягиваются

Comment: Нет, LazyLoad работает по-умолчанию. Никакие соглашения не менял. С другими подобными объектами, где есть связь один-ко-многим навигационные свойства нормально работают.

Comment: Используйте Fluent Api, для описания связи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача была на внимательность )
Как видим тип первичного ключа в таблице Intervals - int, а внешний ключ в таблице Deliveries - short.